# Why can't I import from an extrernal lib's src folder directly?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm by no means a JS expert and I can't figure out why this is not working:

1. Install `@solana/web3.js` library using yarn or npm
2. Try to import from the src folder directly:

```
const {LAMPORTS_PER_SOL} = require('node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/index.ts')
console.log(LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/index.ts'
Require stack:
- /Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/solana-paulx/js/src/sol-api.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/solana-paulx/js/src/sol-api.js:8:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/solana-paulx/js/src/sol-api.js'
  ]
}
```

There can't be a typo in the path because my IDE can follow it no problem.

The variable I'm trying to import is clearly marked for export in the file, so that can't be a problem either.

This must be some JS-specific thing. Why can't I simply import from that file as if it were normal? Is this something to do with it being TypeScript?

Comment: "There can't be a typo in the path because my IDE can follow it no problem" — You need to prefix it with a `./` for local path resolution instead of searching the locations of installed modules (for a package named `node_modules`).

Comment: `const {LAMPORTS_PER_SOL} = require('@solana/web3.js');`

Comment: @Quentin wow that was simple.. feel free to add an answer I'll mark as correct

Comment: @madflow I know how to import from the module the normal way, I was asking specifically how to import from the src folder the direct way.

Comment: Same thing. Just append the src/files . But - whatever floats your boat I guess.